# Make centered text start from the same horizontal position as non-centered text

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` and `h2` element. The container that both elements are in has `padding-left: 4%`.

I want the `h2` and `ul` elements to both start from the same horizontal position so that they're directly below each other. The problem is that as the contents of the `li` elements are centered, the first element is not directly below the `h2` - there's a gap:

[image]

If I add `margin-left: -3%` to the first `li` element, it pushes it to the left and removes the gap:

[image]

But they're not exactly aligned and I'd have to fiddle around with the margin to make it exact. Is there an alternative way to make them directly start from the same point?

```css
#menu {
  background: #bb1919;
  padding: 0 4%;
}

#menu h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li:first-of-type {
  /* margin-left: -2%; */
}

#menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

#menu li:first-of-type p {
  border-left: none;
}

#menu li p {
  border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d06b;
  padding: 0 14px;
  margin: 14px 0 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <h1>NEWS</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>Home</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Coronavirus</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>UK</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>World</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Business</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Politics</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/naq0mb48/

Comment: Nope, there is no CSS layout method that can do this. Adjusting margins/padding is really your own option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:first-of-type` rules for `li` and the `p` inside `li` to set `margin-left` and `padding-left` to `0` and `text-align` to `left`.

ADDITION after comment:

You can add `margin-left: -14px; text-indent: 14px;` to the `#menu li:first-of-type` rule to achieve the desired underline left of the left-aligned first menu entry on hover.

```css
#menu {
  background: #bb1919;
  padding: 0 4%;
}

#menu h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

#menu li p {
  border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d06b;
  padding: 0 14px;
  margin: 14px 0 8px 0;
}

#menu li:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: -14px;
  text-indent: 14px;

}
#menu li:first-of-type p {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <h1>NEWS</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>Home</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Coronavirus</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>UK</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>World</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Business</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Politics</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with this is the fist `li` isn't centered - so it's not in the center of the underline that appears when its hovered over

Comment: please note my addition (and changed snippet code) to the answer

Comment: Does this method guarantee it will be directly below the text? Or will it be a few (even tiny) pixels out?

Comment: The text itself is left aligned (i.e. aligned with the header), then moved to the left by 14px (i.e. the padding value you used yourself for the other elements) through `margin-left: 14px` and moved back to the right by 14px through `text-indent: 14px`. Minus 14px and Plus 14px always will sum up to zero...